# Player is not teleported correctly (MissingReferenceException)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When my Player (GameObject) meets Lava, they should respawn in a specific scene.

This is the code I have assigned to the Player:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Lava")
    {
        GameObject.Find("Controller").GetComponent<Controller>().Respawn();
    }
}
```

Controller is a GameObject, that I don't want to Destroy by Changing level, so this is the code for my Controller GameObject:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static bool created = false;
    public static Controller instance;

    GameObject Player;
    Vector3 respawnPoint;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance = null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            return;
        }

        if (!created)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
            created = true;
            Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
            respawnPoint = GameObject.Find("RespawnPoint").transform.position;
        }
    }

    public void Respawn()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        Player.transform.position = respawnPoint;
    }
}
```

RespawnPoint is just an invisible Cube GameObject, where I want the player to respawn.

Let's say the Game Starts with Scene "0" (this is where the RespawnPoint is, too.)
Then the Player goes to Scene "1" and dies (meets Lava). Then I want the Game to change back to Scene "0" and teleport the Player to the RespawnPoint.

The Scene-Change works good, but the player always starts at the same position, where he starts the first time and he's not teleported to the RespawnPoint.

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: This is strange. The code looks right but the behavior is like you don't have `DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);` in the code...but you do. Have you tried adding a breakpoint in your code and debugging step-by-step to see how the code is actually executing?

Comment: I suspect that this is because changing scenes is not an automic action, as such your code attempts to teleport the player to the respawn point (which may not exist) before the scene has actually changed.

Comment: does your respawnPoint also have a "DontDestroyOnLoad" If it doesnt then that is why your code is failing.  when you load a new scene objects in the current scene that are not marked as "DontDestroyOnLoad" are removed, thus making your respawn point null.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you lack the "==" in the first 'if' from the Awake: `if (instance == null`

The code is fine or it does seem so to me, but the RespawnPoint should be in the Scene your Player meets the lava not in the Scene you are loading. If not the starting position of the player will always be (0,0,0).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend coming to this in a completely different way. I would make a `public Transform[] Spawnpoints`. Since the transform is public you can assign different objects to it. Make an empty game object and position it where you want to spawn. Then use

```
Void OnTriggerEnter(collider2D, other){
    if(other.gameObject.tag == lava) {
        transform.position = spawnpoints[0].position;
    }
}
```

In the inspector set the Transform to be a size of 1 and set the respawn GameObject as the one transform.

Comment: This would work if he wasn't changing scenes.  Since he is loading a new scene, it unloads the current scene and then loads the new scene.  Unless all of those objects are marked as "DontDestroyOnLoad" They would be removed and still cause the NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your answers, they helped me solving this problem.

I added a "DontDestroyOnLoad" to the RespawnPoint and than i changed the Controller Code to this:

```
{
    private static bool created = false;
    public static Controller instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            return;
        }

        if (!created)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
            created = true;
        }
    }

    public void Respawn()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position = GameObject.Find("RespawnPoint").transform.position;
    }
}
```

now the player gets teleported to the correct RespawnPoint. Thanks for your help!